# How to list all canceled subscriptions in Stripe API PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

Here in the docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list

it says

> By default, returns a list of subscriptions that have not been
> canceled. In order to list canceled subscriptions, specify
> status=canceled.

> The status of the subscriptions to retrieve. Passing in a value of
> canceled will return all canceled subscriptions, including those
> belonging to deleted customers. Pass ended to find subscriptions that
> are canceled and subscriptions that are expired due to incomplete
> payment. Passing in a value of all will return subscriptions of all
> statuses.

Basically I need to know how to pass the status parameter because

```
$subs = $stripe->subscriptions->all(
  ['price' => $plan],
  $key
);
```

this works but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Got
> unexpected keys in options array: status in
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/Util/RequestOptions.php:143
> Stack trace: #0
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/Util/RequestOptions.php(59):
> Stripe\Util\RequestOptions::parse(Array, true) #1
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/BaseStripeClient.php(131):
> Stripe\Util\RequestOptions->merge(Array, true) #2
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/BaseStripeClient.php(154):
> Stripe\BaseStripeClient->request('get', '/v1/subscriptio...', Array,
> Array) #3
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/Service/AbstractService.php(64):
> Stripe\BaseStripeClient->requestCollection('get',
> '/v1/subscriptio...', Array, Array) #4
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/Service/SubscriptionService.php(22):
> Stripe\Service\AbstractService->requestCollection('get',
> '/v1/subscriptio...', Array, Array) #5
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/ in
> /home2/deserul7/public_html/stripe_api/stripe-php/lib/Util/RequestOptions.php
> on line 143

when i try this:

```
$subs = $stripe->subscriptions->all(
  ['price' => $plan],
  ['status' => 'canceled']
  $key
);
```

any and all help would be greatly appreciated! PHP is not my strong suit.

Comment: Change to `$stripe->subscriptions->all(
  ['price' => $plan, 'status' => 'canceled'],
  $key
)`

Comment: @catcon oh my god thank you <3 Please place as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since status is part of the parameter, you should add to the parameter array. Change your code to:

```
$subs = $stripe->subscriptions->all(
  [
    'price' => $plan,
    'status' => 'canceled'
  ],
  $key
);
```